# How to search record if field contain slashes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to search records based on my `erp_no`
my `erp_no` field is varchar in my table.

I am using the following query to search

```
SELECT * FROM `invoice` WHERE erp_no LIKE '%SORD\WH03\17\0002917%'
```

But it's returning the empty result set 
may I know what is the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use escaping sequence for backslash

```
 SELECT * FROM `invoice` WHERE erp_no LIKE '%SORD\\WH03\\17\\0002917%'
```

looking to your sample you should use

```
 SELECT * FROM `invoice` WHERE erp_no ='SORD\\WH03\\17\\0002917'
```

Comment: show me a sample of  the content  of erp_no  you are trying to select

Comment: I added screenshot

Comment: the try a partial match eg: LIKE '%WH03\\17%'